# Euler's method for differential equations (estimation)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

Is it true that if a curve is **increasing**, Euler's method will *always* **underestimate** an actual solution?

So if a curve is either increasing and concave down, or increasing and concave up, we can simply ignore concavity and justify the answer based on the fact that it's increasing?

Euler's method will therefore underestimate whenever the function is concave down and increasing, or concave up and increasing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are correct, the effect depends on how the exact solution curves away from the tangent that the Euler method follows. Left-curving or convex solutions lead to an underestimate by Euler, right--curving or concave to an over-estimate.

Comment: If Euler's method uses tangent lines, it will underestimate an increasing function as long as it's concave up. But if the function is increasing and the concavity is down, it will overestimate. Therefore, the question must be false, because it's not always true that it underestimates. Is that correct?